# Multiple user forms into one column

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a code that opens a user form when a specific text value is entered into a cell in a specific column and enters the data from that user form into the cell in the column next to it.
(e.g., if you type 'Happy' any cell in the C column, a user form for happiness will appear.)

I created 2 other user form duplicates that I want to code in the same column but based on 2 different text values.
(e.g., in column C 'Happy' any cell in the C column a user form for happiness will appear, if you type 'sad' any cell in the C column, a user form for sadness will appear, and if you type 'angry' any cell in the C column, a user form for angriness will appear.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Value = "Opportunity" Then

       Set AddressCell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
       OpportunityForm.Show

    End If

End Sub
```

[User Form Change Code] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM0on.jpg)

I tried copy and pasting exactly as is but an error message appears regarding "Complile error: Ambiguous name detected: Worksheet_Change".

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change` event sub must be associated with a specific worksheet - so it must be in the code module for that worksheet. In other words, I suspect that your `Worksheet_Change` code is in a general code module. Just move it to the sheet.

Comment: Looks to me like you pasted the code into a module AND into a worksheet - You don't want it to be in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Like this maybe:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub 'only handling single-cell changes
    
    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        Select Case LCase(Target.Value)
            Case "happy": HappyForm.Show
            Case "sad": SadForm.Show
            Case "angry": AngryForm.Show
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: None of the user forms appear when I type in Column C

Comment: Make sure that (1) The code is in the worksheet code module for the sheet where you're entering data (2) `Application.EnableEvents` is `True`

Answer (score -2):

I figured it out. I inputted commands for multiple conditions using 'If' and 'ElseIf' codes. I will leave an example for anyone who has this issue as well (please note I already created a public code called "AddressCell" in a module):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'If condition 1 Then
'Code to execute
'ElseIf condition 2 Then
'Code to execute
'ElseIf condition 3 Then
'Code to execute
'End If

    If Target.Column = 6 And Target.Value = "Opportunity" Then

        Set AddressCell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
        OpportunityForm.Show
    
    ElseIf Target.Column = 6 And Target.Value = "Quoting" Then

        Set AddressCell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
        QuotingForm.Show
        
    ElseIf Target.Column = 6 And Target.Value = "Execution" Then

        Set AddressCell = Target.Offset(0, 1)
        ExecutionForm.Show
    End If
End Sub
```